# Добавить в следующий запрос GET параметр, если он уже есть в текущем

Tags: javascript, php, url

Задача такова, есть запрос в котором может быть get параметр, например "example=1", как мне реализовать добавление этого параметра ко всем следующим переходам, желательно и к ajax запросам? Хранить этот параметр в куках или сессии не вариант - может быть открыта вторая вкладка. Надо добавлять лишь в случае, если в урле присутствует уже этот параметр.

Comment: кукам и сессии пофик сколько у вас вкладок, они работают для всего сайта, в отличии от localStorage, он для каждой вкладки свой, но добавлять его к запросам придется самостоятельно

Comment: вы про sessionStorage? я вот про него читаю [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage)

Comment: Да, именно, но эти данные на сервер автоматически не отправляются. если вам они нужны на стороне сервера - передавать придется в ручную!

Comment: спасибо, но это не решает вопроса с сохранением и передачей ссылок, мне уже указали на данную дополнительную опцию.

Answer (score 0):

Допустип унас урл будет: http://my-site/page?example=1

На странице (скрипт) которая обрабатывает запрос извлекаем его:

```
$params = ['example' => $_GET['example']];
$href='http://my-site/your-new-page?' . http_build_query($params )
//получаем ссылку http://my-site/your-new-page?example=1
```

А теперь используем например в html:

```
<a href="<?php echo $href ?>" id="link">Link</a>
```

Или в Ajax при нажатии на кнопку:

```
<button id="link" data-href="<?php echo $href ?>">Link</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#link').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $(this).attr('data-href'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response)
        {
            ...
        }
   });
 });
</script>
```

или

```
<button id="link" data-href="<?php echo $_GET['example'] ?>">Link</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://my-site/your-new-page?example=' . $(this).attr('data-href') ,
            success: function(response)
            {
                ...
            }
       });
     });
    </script>
```

И так далее...
Вообщем вариантов много) Пробуйте) 
Не гарантирую синтаксическую верность моего кода) Но я думаю суть понятна)

Comment: да, спасибо, видимо так и придется делать, добавлять к каждому урлу, но это накладно, поскольку надо переходить на различные роуты, то есть правки делать везде.

Comment: @JohnRoget а как вы хотели? )